# Появление двух элементов через before и after

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь настроить чтобы при клике на значок подсказки (знак вопроса) появлялись 2 блока: 1й это полупрозрачный темный фон, 2й блок — с самой подсказкой, но почему то появляется только один — тот, который с подсказкой. Как сделать чтобы фон тоже появлялся?

```css
span.support::after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  width: 370px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  z-index: 770px;
}

span.support:focus::after {
  display: block;
}

span.support::before {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(41, 44, 44, 0.9);
  background: rgba(41, 44, 44, 0.9);
  z-index: 760px;
}

span.support:focus::before {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div style="color: #378B28; font-size: 18px;">Краткий текст описания
  <span class='support' tabindex="1" data-title='Текст подсказки'>
   <em>?</em>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для таких блоков `before` и `after` всегда должен быть задан `content`, через `css` что бы они появились, и поскольку у вас блок `before` не должен был содержать какой то контент я задал в его атрибуте просто пустую строку - `content: ''`, и сейчас все работает.

```css
span.support::after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  width: 370px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  z-index: 770px;
}

span.support:focus::after {
  display: block;
}

span.support::before {
  content: '';
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(41, 44, 44, 0.9);
  background: rgba(41, 44, 44, 0.9);
  z-index: 760px;
}

span.support:focus::before {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div style="color: #378B28; font-size: 18px;">Краткий текст описания
  <span class='support' tabindex="1" data-title='Текст подсказки'>
   <em>?</em>
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Чтобы псевдоэлементы отображались, необходимо чтобы у них было свойство `content`, пусть даже пустое.
2. `z-index` — это натуральное число, он не измеряется в пикселях.
3. Переносить текст в свойстве `content` можно при помощи `\A` и свойства `white-space: pre`.

```css
span.support::after {
  content: attr(data-title);
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -200px;
  width: 370px;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  z-index: 770;
}

span.support:focus::after {
  display: block;
}

span.support::before {
  display: none;
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(41, 44, 44, 0.9);
  background: rgba(41, 44, 44, 0.9);
  z-index: 760;
}

span.support:focus::before {
  display: block;
}

.content-newline::after {
  content: 'first line \A second line';
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div style="color: #378B28; font-size: 18px;">Краткий текст описания
  <span class='support' tabindex="1" data-title='Текст подсказки'>
   <em>?</em>
  </span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="content-newline"></div>
```

Comment: а еще вопросик можно ли в content делать как то переносы?

Comment: см. обновленный ответ.